# Where to put amphp directory?

Tags: php, composer-php, amphp

I downloaded amphp using composer and it automatically downloaded it to`C:\Users\<myusername>` is that where  it's meant to be for usage or do I need to copy it to my local servers directory or `htdocs`?

Comment: Composer installs stuff by default in a `vendor` subdirectory below working directory so you're supposed to `cd` to wherever your source code is before running `composer require amphp/amp`.

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/). This question isn't specific to Amp, but is rather a generic Composer question.